# split string containing many whitespace in c++

Tags: c++, file, split, line

how can I split a string containing many spaces.like for exemple this string(it is line from text file) 
***`12          145        ready`***

i work with old version of C++( i dont have c++11) and i don't know how i can do this!. I tried

```
stringstream(line.substr(positionOfElement,string::npos))
stringstream(line.substr(positionOfElement,string::npos))
```

it's work but it is bad for me because  I need to know the position of element in my string. there is a simple way?

Comment: Use `std::istringstream` and `operator>>()`

Comment: Since you need to know the position of each token I would suggest you loop over the characters, and store and index or a pointer each time you find a nonblank that is immediately preceded by a blank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank you for your answers. I find a answer, and in resolve my problem like this:

```
string line("124       24    ready");
istringstream iss(line);
vector<string> tokens;
       copy(istream_iterator<string>(iss),
            istream_iterator<string>(),
            back_inserter(tokens));
```

Comment: You could make your solution a bit shorter by using std::vector's ctor that takes two iterators: `vector<string> tokens(istream_iterator<string>(iss),             istream_iterator<string>());`